# Как правильно писать свое имя в резюме и в деловой переписке?

Tags: деловой-язык

**Иван Иванов** или **Иванов Иван**? Есть ли какие-либо нормы деловой этики - что писать раньше: фамилию или имя? В английском, я знаю, сперва имя, потом фамилия, а в русском?

*Например:*

> Добрый день,
>
> прошу рассмотреть мою кандидатуру на должность: Программист Java.
>
> С уважением,
> Иванов Иван.

**З.Ы.** Отчество после имени сразу - это понятно. **Иван Иванович**. У англичан отчества нету.

Comment: Вверху - фамилия, имя, отчество (Иванов Иван Иванович), внизу можно ничего не писать, даже подпись можно не ставить, но если ставите  - то сначала инициалы. (И. И. Иванов)   https://rezyume-obrazec.ru/

Comment: В шапке вверху всегда пишут полностью фамилию, имя, отчество, а вот в подписи раньше тоже было в таком порядке, а теперь уже много лет подряд в расшифровке подписи инициалы, фамилия, а если просто подпись - Иван Иванов, в деловой переписке: С уважением, Иван Иванов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сошлюсь на [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=265511):

**Вопрос № 265511**

> Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какой последовательности нужно писать имена-отчества (или инициалы) и фамилии людей в текстах,
>   предназначенных для размещения в СМИ, или в презентационных
>   материалах. Слышала мнение о том, что если человек жив, сначала
>   пишутся имя и отчество, а потом фамилия, для умерших людей - наоборот.
>   Если ли какое-то специальное правило?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Никогда не доводилось слышать о таком правиле (про живых и умерших). Фамилия пишется перед именем и отчеством (или инициалами) в
>   алфавитных пофамильных списках, в библиографии. В остальных случаях
>   имя и отчество (а также инициалы) пишутся перед фамилией.

Не думаю, что это правило настолько принципиально в деловом этикете, но раз в Вашей ситуации оно совпадает с "международными привычками", тогда и сомнений нет. (Иначе я бы поостерёгся с таким советом — на основании личного опыта.)